# What is the current status of windicators?

Tags: development, windicators

This cool feature was first told to be included in **10.10**. According to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3530/whats-happening-with-windicators/3533#3533), they were postponed to 11.04, but it turned out they have not appeared there. Now we are after feature freeze for **11.10**, and still there is no sign of them. So what's up with them?

I haven't heard a word about them for a long time. Is this idea ***abandoned***? Note it was initially the reason for moving the window-ops buttons to the left corner. Or maybe they are under heavy development and soon will be included in 12.04?

Comment: I have sent a message to mpt, interface designer at canonical, to see if he can answer this. If I get a reply I will post it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't heard *anything* about Windicators since I answered that last question. I admit I'm not everywhere and I don't see everything but I'd have expected to have seen something if development was ongoing.

The problem with them is they'd be a complete nightmare to implement just to do half the things Mark was hoping they would... Especially if you want to do that in a nice, standard way that works for all applications.

The effort is far better spent on making Unity good.

I consider Windicators abandoned -- but I'm not in charge of anything :) They may well get pulled up later on but I can't say if or when that'll happen.